# How to synchronize two tables stored in different databases

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables in different databases. The tables are exactly alike (same name,same columns,etc). My question is, how can I retrieve new rows from parent table and store into the child table? I need to do so in a click_event of a button.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what the table structures look like. Which RDBMS you are using. One way update or both ways?

Comment: I need to do it in both directions. Updation should be based on the id field. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to keep the tables always in sync, or just specific rows at specific times?

Comment: Have you considered Replication ?

Comment: I have already mentioned that, I need to do on a btnClick event of a button from my winForm. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several technologies specifically for this type of scenario:

- [SQL Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

  - Supports unidirectional or bidirectional synchronization
- [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)

  - Lets you define the mappings of the data, as well as transformations, and attach other code to the process easily
- [Linked-servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

  - Allows you to query databases and tables on remote servers as though they are part of the local database.  Very easy to setup (just call `exec sp_addlinkedserver`) and once defined uses nothing but plain old SQL

---

Since you mention this needs to occur on a button-click then I'd suggest you use linked servers within a stored procedure--they're the simplest option.  SSIS would also be suitable, you'd need to execute the package on the button-click.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it myself using Linked Server. [Here](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-add-sql-server-linked-server.aspx) is a simple tutorial about how to create a linked server.
After creating linked server, we can query it as follows:

```
select * from LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
```

Works just perfect!!
Accepting STW's answer as he explains different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

(long and non-optimal solution)
get all id's from first table.
get all id's from second table.
loop through the first array and remove all items that are found in the second.

Comment: As you said, it would be a non-optimal solution since the table contains tens of thousands of records. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This method will cause headaches, I do not recommend it. What happens if you have 100 entries in each table and a user adds another one to each? Then you would have to compare the data in each record to get the differences, but what happens if the user changes the data... I could go on. There are a few solutions to this problem as @STW states